# javascript outputting the same score twice instead of adding one each time (closed)

Tags: javascript

im having trouble with my javascript outputting a score of the same value twice instead of it adding one each time. here is my code:

```
if (points > document.getElementById("score").value) {
    document.getElementById("score").value = points;
} else if (document.getElementById("score").value >= points) {
    points = parseFloat(document.getElementById("score").value);
    pointTitle.innerHTML = "Points: " + parseFloat(document.getElementById("score").value);
}
```

the code a duplicate of the old score twice then adds one instead of adding the old score once then adding one. eg of code pattern: 59, 59, 60 61 etc. eg of what i want: 59, 60, 61 etc. if anyone could help i would appreciate it!

ps. points is a integer and score is a string but i convert the string to an integer then back into a string with the last 2 lines of code

Comment: Can you provide examples of `score`, and `points`. `points` might be a number, and score will be a string so you won't be able to compare them properly.

Comment: @Andy points is an integer that represents the score and score is a string that has been converted to an integer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in trying to compare different types. Try something more like this:

```js
// Presumably points is set somewhere above, ideally as a number type
// ...
let scoreValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("score").value);
if (!Number.isFinite(scoreValue)) {
    scoreValue = 0;
}

if (points > scoreValue) {
    document.getElementById("score").value = points;
} else if (scoreValue >= points) {
    points = scoreValue;
    pointTitle.innerHTML = "Points: " + scoreValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The value of "score" will be a string, so you need to coerce it to a number which you're not currently doing.
2. You should cache your score element to reduce your code content.

```js
let points = 100;

const score = document.querySelector('#score');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const pointTitle = document.querySelector('#pointTitle');

button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {

  // Coerce `score.value` to an integer
  if (points > +score.value) {
    score.value = points;
  } else {
    points = score.value;
    pointTitle.textContent = `Points: ${score.value}`;
  }

  console.log(points);

}
```

```html
<input id="score" />
<button>Click</button>
<div id="pointTitle" />
```